# getting a url by clicking on a link

Tags: java, url

i have a simple question. is there any method or class or etc that when clicking a link, it gives us the URL address?

then when on a browser we click on a link, we get the url as a string which is a URL type.
something similar to what a ProgressBar shows but i just need the final adr.

Comment: Can you specify your question a little bit more?

Comment: Have you tried just using toString()?

Comment: Do you by any chance mean that when clicking on a link in your browser, you'll get that URL in some way in you application? Cuz if that's what you mean, then there's basically no way for java to do this alone... except through JNDI... but then you're talking c/c++.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean  similar to what you said, but imagine im using a lay out engine which is written in java, then?

Comment: too little info dude. Basically if you have written the code OR have access to it and modify it, you can simply add an MouseListener to your component, and do whatever you want with it. Are you using Swing? cuz i could give you exact code for that.... anyway, share code, or info, i have no idea what you actually want to ask. (i won't downrate your question, cuz i'm not an asshole, but please try to be more specific)

Comment: @vlad-ardelean nobody said you are asswhole, no need to use that language too :) well how about giving a try for mouse listener? for sawing :) if i didnt make it too specific just wanted see how many ways are there and then choosing the best one

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the return values of some URL class methods:

```
public String getURLAdress(URL url)
{
   return url.getProtocol()+ "://"+ url.getHost() + url.getPath();
}
```

Comment: how to make it work on a OnClick event on a link? i mean, imagine using a browser engine. then when click on the link, using this method to get the adr of the link that user clicked, did i make it clear? :)

Comment: how is a link defined? is it a text within html tags? is it a text of a jlabel? your question is not clear at all.

Comment: first one. a text within html tags :P is there any common method for doing what i want? then i can search it in the library of the specific engine